# unlimited free admission

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am wondering what the difference between *unlimited free admission* and *unlimited admission* in the following. Suppose the pass allows a person to visit an amusement park.

The Happy Pass, which costs $120, offers **unlimited (free) admission** for 12 months.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

“Unlimited” admission means that for the period of validity of the pass, the holder may visit as many times as desired.

“Free” admission means that for the period of validity of the pass, any given visit requires no additional payment of an admission fee.

A pass that offers “free” admission may be good for a fixed period, or for a specified number of visits, whichever occurs first.

A pass that offers “unlimited” admission for a fixed period may require a (discounted) payment for each admission.

A pass that offers “unlimited free” admission for a fixed period will not require payment for any admission within the period of validity, and the holder may visit as many times as desired within that period.

Comment: To some extent "unlimited free admission" is redundant in order to make it absolutely clear what the pass includes.  "Unlimited admission" would only  *suggest* all visits would be free.

Comment: @Andrew your analysis is supported by the fact that "free" is in parentheses.  This suggests that the author recognized that its inclusion was not strictly necessary.

Comment: Don"t you think there would be a contracontradiction if "free" were included? After all, the pass costs $120.

Comment: "Free" does not necessarily mean that you don't pay for ANYTHING, but that you don't pay for this specific thing. In this case, you pay for the pass, and then there is no additional charge for each admission. Advertisements will often say things like, "Buy 1, get 1 free!", or "If you buy this car now, we'll include a premium stereo system absolutely free!", etc. The idea is, you paid for one thing, and then you get something else for free. (Of course often you're not really getting anything for free, the price of thing #2 is simply rolled into thing #1. But that's another story.)

Comment: I agree that the idea "you paid for one thing, and then you get something else for free' works for your car example and "buy one, get one free" case. But it's doubtful whether the reasoning extends naturally to the pass case. After all, when a person pays for the pass, they are buying a pass that allows them to make as many visits they want. It's nothing like "if you buy this pass, you will get a second pass for free."

Comment: @Apollyon Well, actually, if you really want a *natural extension*, divide the cost of the pass by the cost of a single ticket, then notice that past that point you get to visit the amusement park an infinite number of times for free. I.e., if, e.g., a single ticket costs $12, you pay for 10 visits in advance and **get** to visit the place as many times as you want afterwards, free of charge. (: I'm not sure why it's so difficult for you to grasp the concept – you're paying for a separate product when you buy the pass.

Comment: Why not divide the cost of the pass by the number of actual visits to the amusement park? Suppose that a single ticket cost $12, and you visited the  amusement park only five times in a year. Then the pass would still be not free.

Comment: Another line of thought is, as you've mentioned, is regard the pass as a product distinct from a $12 ticket. Then the price of a single ticket would NOT serve as standard of reference. Still, the pass is not free; after all, it costs $120. This is the most straightforward interpretation, I suppose.

Comment: If you buy something, then it's not free, not even nominally.

Comment: The situation of the pass is different from one in which you buy a car, and the car dealer gives you a car stereo system; the gift would be nominally 
described as "free," though actually its cost is simply passed on to the consumer. In contrast, the pass is not free, not even nominally. After all, unlimited admission to the amusement park for a year is what the pass is all about.

Comment: To insist the annual pass is free is like a car dealer's claiming, "I have something for sale. It costs $20,000. It is a free VW Passat W8."

Comment: @Apollyon I'm afraid the match is exact: You bought 10 tickets = you bought a car; you get the subsequent tickets free of charge = you get the stereo free of charge.

Comment: You didn't get the message; there is no match here. Particularly important is the difference between pass and ticket. You substituted 10 tickets for a pass. Also important is the fact that the pass is what is being labeled for sale. What is offered on sale CANNOT BE CLAIMED TO BE FREE.

Comment: Would a car dealer ever claim his cars are FREE? No. How about a car stereo system? Yes.

Comment: Unlimited admission is the essence of the pass; the essence of a commodity cannot be claimed to be free, because there are legal consequences involving the refund mechanism.

Comment: @Apollyon It's not important how it's labeled. Because if you only look at it that way, you can't make any *natural extensions*; instead, you have to look at it on its face. I don't know what kinda legal consequences you're talking about, but I'm sure the contract behind that pass will tell you exactly how you can't cheat it.

Comment: So if you wanna be smart about it, you can look at it through the natural extension and see what you're getting. *Free* is there in contrast to a certain amount, as this answer explains. For example, my bus pass costs a certain amount, but I still have to pay about 10% of the original cost of the ticket every time I make a trip. I have unlimited monthly rides but the cost of each ride is reduced. If you look at it as a different product it's even easier to understand how they're allowed to call it free. Because yes, in that model, buying a single ticket gives you a free ride.

Comment: Of course this is absurd, but you're paying for the ticket, the product; not the ride.